# Angular, AWS, S3: Upload without entire individual user authentication infrastructure

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

1. I have an S3 bucket.
2. I have an IAM user with permission to connect to the bucket.
3. I would like to build an Angular application which uses that user to connect to the bucket when running locally.

This would be straightforward in Java. Include the AWS SDK, pick up the access key etc. from local configuration, connect, do stuff.

In Angular I am feeling completely lost. Is there any way to do the equivalent thing?

I've added the AWS SDK for JavaScript to my project, but the modules aren't recognized as Angular modules.

I've tried configuring AWS Amplify. When I try to add "storage", it also wants to set up authentication, and then it's asking me whether individual users will authenticate with a phone number or email, and I feel like I'm on completely the wrong track.

Can someone set me straight? Is what I want to do actually impossible in AWS + Angular? Am I going to have to use vanilla JS to accomplish it?

Comment: 'going to have to use vanilla JS' - what other way exists? Include the AWS SDK, pick up the access key etc. from local configuration, connect, do stuff. It won't be in an Angular module but that doesn't stop you.